# Assigning text file to array

Tags: arrays, file, input, while-loop

What I'm trying to do is get the values from a text value and then put them into an array of doubles. This is what I have but it doesn't accomplish my goal and prints out something that I don't want instead. I can't use array lists in this, just arrays.

This is what is in the text file: *70.3   70.8   73.8   77.0   80.7   83.4   84.5   84.4   83.4   80.2   76.3   72.0*

Code:

```
    Scanner temperatureFile = new Scanner(new File("KeyWestTemp.txt"));
    double [] temperature = new double[12];

    while(temperatureFile.hasNext())
    {
        temperature[index] = temperatureFile.nextDouble();
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you initialize `index` to zero.  Then check that the number you get from the `Scanner` is correct by printing the value out inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the problem, but I might be wrong :-)

```
temperature[11] = temperatureFile.nextDouble(); // index?
```

To elaborate, you should have something like:

```
i = 0; // index 'runner'
while(temperatureFile.hasNext())
{
    temperature[i] = temperatureFile.nextDouble();
    i++;
}
```

However, this is not generic and you should really make an estimation of the size before declaring the array size.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about that part but it still doesn't come out correctly when I use index and increment it by 1 each time.

Comment: For some reason, my output is this "[D@81b1fb". That's really strange

Comment: Judging by your comment down here, you're printing the address instead of the value. Make sure you print a double using the correct index.

If you're struggling let me see your printing code.

Answer (score 0):

Reut has the right idea.  You are only ever assigning to the last element of the temperature array.  Try:

```
for (int i = 0; temperatureFile.hasNext() && (i < 12); i++) {
    temperature[i] = temperatureFile.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: This helps but for some reason I get this when I output. "[D@81b1fb". That random string of characters isn't what I want.